# XPath - Selecting multiple nodes on different levels depending on an attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

If my XML looks like:

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <a>
            <b>Some text</b>
        </a>
        <c>
            <d>Some other text</d>
        </c>
        <e type="Blah">123</e>
    </entry>
    <entry> ... </entry>
</root>
```

How can I select all the `<b>` and `<d>` from the entries where the type of `<e>` is equal to "Blah"?

I tried something like:

```
//entry/a/b[../../e[@type="Blah"] | //entry/c/d[../../e[@type="Blah"]
```

But that only returns the `<b>`'s. Note: If it matters, I'm running this from Saxon HE 9.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
//entry[e[@type='Blah']]//*[name() = 'b' or name() = 'd']
```

Demo here - http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/e93421dcb67f914b11108ddabb53d1dc

Comment: The query before the edit works fine too. Is there a reason to use the updated one over the old one?

Comment: @rkman I couldn't get the first one to work on the demo site :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the double slash `//` to match all decendants of a particular node. For example:

```
//entry[//e/@type="Blah"]
```

This will return all entry nodes *anywhere* in the documents (`//` at the front matches all nodes), that have an `e` decendant *anywhere* underneath them, with an attribute of `type` equalling `"Blah"`.

Comment: How do I go about selecting two children nodes from entry?

Comment: That depends on the host langauge calling the XPath, but the above Xpath will return a node-set of *all* matching nodes.